# Converting long image to paged pdf

Tags: image, pdf, imagemagick

I'm using imagick to convert a png to pdf:

```
convert file.png file.pdf
```

Now I get a pdf with only one page and have a problem with printing that pdf.

Is it possible to automatically split png to create pdf with pages fitted to A4 format?

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure how/where you want to split your large PNG image, but this should give you some ideas. First, let's determine a very approximate size for a sheet of A4 - some printers are borderless and some can't get near the edges of the paper, so if we say, for argument's sake, A4 is 8 inches by 11, then at 144 dpi (also a guess) you will get around 1,152 pixels by 1,584 pixels on a page of A4.

So, we hack your image into lumps no bigger than that, and *repage* them so they *forget* where they came from in the original image. We then save the resulting A4-sized chunks as `page000.png`, `page0001.png` etc.

```
convert image.png -crop 1152x1584 +repage page%03d.png
```

Now we can put them all back together as a PDF with this

```
convert -density 144 page*png result.pdf
```

Obviously this simple method has no concept of where is a sensible place to chop your image so it may go around cutting at unfortunate places!

As commented by @Danack, you can obviate the need for the intermediate files and go straight to the output PDF like this:

```
convert image.png -crop 1152x1584 +repage output.pdf
```

Let's try it out. First create a big gradient PNG

```
convert -size 3000x4000 gradient:black-white image.png
```

[image]

Now chop that puppy up...

```
convert image.png -crop 1152x1584 +repage page%03d.png
```

that gives 9 pages like this:

```
identify page*
page000.png PNG 1152x1584 1152x1584+0+0 16-bit sRGB 9.68KB 0.000u 0:00.000
page001.png[1] PNG 1152x1584 1152x1584+0+0 16-bit sRGB 9.68KB 0.000u 0:00.000
page002.png[2] PNG 696x1584 696x1584+0+0 16-bit sRGB 8.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
page003.png[3] PNG 1152x1584 1152x1584+0+0 16-bit sRGB 9.71KB 0.000u 0:00.000
page004.png[4] PNG 1152x1584 1152x1584+0+0 16-bit sRGB 9.71KB 0.000u 0:00.000
page005.png[5] PNG 696x1584 696x1584+0+0 16-bit sRGB 8.32KB 0.000u 0:00.000
page006.png[6] PNG 1152x832 1152x832+0+0 16-bit sRGB 5.21KB 0.000u 0:00.000
page007.png[7] PNG 1152x832 1152x832+0+0 16-bit sRGB 5.21KB 0.000u 0:00.000
page008.png[8] PNG 696x832 696x832+0+0 16-bit sRGB 4.48KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

And put them back together, as a PNG for display here, but the Pdf is no different:
[image]

Comment: Can't you skip direct to the PDF with `convert image.png -crop 1152x1584 +repage page.pdf` ?

Comment: @Danack Yes, indeed, thank you. I was too carried away demonstrating the sizes of the intermediate files and considering ordering them differently that I omitted to simplify the command - I'll add it in, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to tell ImageMagick to do the cropping to a tileset

```
convert -crop 1x16@  AHw1w.png -page 200x100 tile.pdf
```

This splits the input image into 16 sections high, and 1 across, and then renders them onto a pdf for which the pages are sized 200 by 100.